# SQL Server - Duplicate Keys Error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm running an SQL stored procedure which inserts records into a table from 2 different tables. Since there is a primary key constraint on the table that is being inserted, the exception `Duplicate key was ignored` raises. But when I call the SP from my C# windows form application this raises the exception and the execution stops. How do I handle this? My C# code is below:

```
qry = "Exec Database.dbo.spname '" + searchvalue + "'";

if (rs.State == 1) { 
   rs.Close(); 
}

rs.Open(qry, sqltbl.GetSqlConnection());
```

I get an exception error on the `rs.Open` line

Comment: Please parametrise your code!!!

Comment: I don't get you @Larnu are you asking me to edit my question or the code..??

Comment: I'm *telling* you that you shouldn't concatenate your strings like like that when executing a query. Imagien if the variable `searchvalue` had the value: `1'; Use master; ALTER DATABASE [Database] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE [Database];--`. You would (probably) be saying goodbye to your database. You should be parametrising your query, not concatenating strings.

Comment: Thank you Larnu and I'm very much aware of SQL injection and its problems. I sort of made that one up quickly to post a question. The answer that I'm seeking isn't that. Please stick to the agenda. Thanks.

Comment: But what exactly you wanna do? Ignore exception and move on?, if so add `try { rs.Open(qry, sqltbl.GetSqlConnection()); } catch {}` that way you will ignore exception about keys and should move on with execution

Comment: Just because it's an "example" doesn't mean you should be using poor/bad coding practices. Regardless if it is an example or not, string concatenation for a query is bad, and should **never** be done.

Comment: Thank you @Veljko89 that resolved my problem..

Comment: @KarthikeyanNatarajan ignoring exceptions is very bad practice...

Comment: For the last time people.. what I had posted was pretty rough code and isn't the actual one. I simply wanted to put in a context of what I was actually seeking and I DO KNOW ABOUT SQL INJECTION AND ITS CONSEQUENCES. Please read all my comments before posting further. Thanks.  @Caldazar. This goes for you too sir.

Comment: People here are taking too much time in pointing out others mistakes rather than providing / helping with the actual solutions. Stop feeding your ego and at least let the genuine ones to help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the exception is being thrown from the procedure `Database.dbo.spname` you are executing. Exceptions aren't something you should ignore or hide under the couch.

You probably have a statement like the following:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (
    KeyColumn,
    ColumnName)
SELECT
    I.InsertingKeyColumn,
    I.ColumnName
FROM
    SomeOtherTable AS I
```

Make use of the `NOT EXISTS` to check existance of records before trying to insert and the error won't pop up.

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (
    KeyColumn,
    ColumnName)
SELECT
    I.InsertingKeyColumn,
    I.ColumnName
FROM
    SomeOtherTable AS I
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'not yet in SomeTable' FROM SomeTable AS S WHERE I.InsertingKeyColumn = S.KeyColumn)
```